# how to modify the style of chips?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-chips

I need to make the following UI using chips

[image]

I have already implement the chips and make it checkable, but I do not know how to change the style of it to be like the picture

I changed the stroke color and background color and stroke width

so the normal chips has no problem, my problem is with the checked chips which is blue

can anyone advice please ?

Answer (score 17):

Just use a custom style for your [`Chip`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Chip.md):

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
      style="@style/Colors_Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
      ..>
```

with this style:

```
  <style name="Colors_Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/color_choice_chip_background_color</item>
    <item name="chipStrokeColor">@color/color_choice_chip_strokecolor_selector</item>
    <item name="chipStrokeWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_choice_chip_text_color</item>
  </style>
```

where the **`chipBackgroundColor`** is a selector. Something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- 24% opacity -->
  <item android:alpha="0.24" android:color="@color/primaryLightColor" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.24" android:color="@color/primaryLightColor" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <!-- 12% of 87% opacity -->
  <item android:alpha="0.10" android:color="#FFF" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="#FFF"/>
</selector>
```

the **`chipStrokeColor`** and **`android:textColor`** are selectors like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:color="@color/primaryLightColor" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:color="@color/primaryLightColor" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <!-- 87% opacity. -->
  <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="#C6CCCD" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <!-- 38% of 87% opacity. -->
  <item android:alpha="0.33" android:color="#C6CCCD"/>

</selector>
```

The final result:

[image]

Comment: Better mention the file location is res/color/color_choice_chip_background_color.xml

Comment: Remove `android:state_enabled="true"` and `android:state_selected="true"`. It'll save you some time...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `ToggleButton` which can be `checked` or `not checked`. As a `background` you can set file with `states`.

You can create layout with them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="40dp">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:checked="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As `background` you can set file which contains list of states:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_shape" android:state_checked="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/grey_shape" />

</selector>
```

And all of the states (`checked` and `default` - last one) can be shapes:

**res > drawable > grey_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#D6D6D6" />

    <corners android:radius="50dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#727272" />

</shape>
```

**res > drawable > blue_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#81D7FF" />

    <corners android:radius="50dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#1890D1" />

</shape>
```

You can expect different backgound when button is `checked` and `not checked`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First create a custom theme for your `Chip`

Step 1

- create some color selectors
- create color selector for chip background

> res/color/chip_background_color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/chip_background_color_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/chip_background_color_unselected" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

- create color selector for chip text

> res/color/chip_text_color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/chip_text_color_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/chip_text_color_unselected" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

- create color selector for chip stroke/outline

> res/color/chip_stroke_color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/chip_stroke_color_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/chip_stroke_color_unselected" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Step 2

- create custom theme for `Chip`

> res/values/themes.xml

```
<!--You can change the parent class according to your needs-->
<style name="CustomChipStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/chip_background_color_selector</item>
    <item name="chipStrokeColor">@color/chip_stroke_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/chip_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="chipStrokeWidth">@dimen/chip_stroke_width</item>
</style>
```

Step 3

- use `CustomChipStyle` in your `Chip`

  ```
  <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
       android:id="@+id/chip_group"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:checkedChip="@+id/chip_one"
       app:selectionRequired="true"
       app:singleSelection="true">

       <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
           android:id="@+id/chip_one"
           style="@style/CustomChipStyle"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Chip One" />

       <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
           android:id="@+id/chip_two"
           style="@style/CustomChipStyle"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Chip Two" />

       <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
           android:id="@+id/chip_three"
           style="@style/CustomChipStyle"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Chip Three" />
  </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
  ```

Thats it.

also refer [Chip](https://m2.material.io/components/chips/android)

Happy coding..